# How to Insert Multiple Rows in a foreach command with LINQ?

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I wrote these lines:

```
foreach (var catId in CatIds)
{
    AdCategory.AdId = LastAd.AdID;
    AdCategory.CategoryId = catId;
    EngineDB.Ad_Categories.InsertOnSubmit(AdCategory);
    EngineDB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

and CatIds is an Integer Array.
this command inserts first element correctly but next loop causes this exception:
**"Cannot add an entity that already exists."**

How can I fix it. 
please help me as soon as posible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new AdCategory in the loop. Otherwise, as the error states, you are tyring to insert the same object again and again.

You should also move

```
EngineDB.SubmitChanges();
```

outside of the loop so you only make 1 call to the database.

Answer (score 6):

as Jimmie said you need to create a new AdCategory in the loop.  You also probably don't want to call SubmitChanges every time as well, this call uses a transaction to make sure all the items are added at once, or none at all.

Try something like:

```
foreach (var catId in CatIds)
{
    var AdCategory = new AdCategory()
    {
        AdId = LastAd.AdID,
        CategoryId = catId
    }
    EngineDB.Ad_Categories.InsertOnSubmit(AdCategory);
}

EngineDB.SubmitChanges();
```