# Linq Multiple row insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm having trouble with multiple insert row with linq.
i have 2 tables,,

[Subscribe] Table

[image]

and
[Message] Table

- MessageID (int, isIdentity)
- Sender
- Receiver
- Content

i want all  UserName in Subcribe table which subcribe to "Rock" Category
receive one same Messages from me..
my codes now is giving an error

```
    var subcribe = from s in database.Subscribes
                   where s.SubscribeCategory == "Rock"
                   select s.UserName;


    foreach (string s in subcribe)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.MsgContent = "Text Here";
        msg.Sender = this.User.Identity.Name;
        msg.Receiver = s;
        database.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(msg);
    }
    database.SubmitChanges();
```

can anyone help with this query?
thanks before..

Regards..

Comment: Can you include the error please?

Comment: @yuma What's the error ?

Comment: frlllow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854971/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-a-foreach-command-with-linq

Comment: @irsog that case is different; that poster made the mistake of not instantiating a new item for each iteration.

Comment: what's the error you get(after runing)?

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you haven't set the primary key column in the `Message` table so there may be a chance that you are getting this error:

> Can't perform Create, Update or Delete operations on `Table(Message)` because it has no primary key.

For that you have to add a primary key in the `Message` table and then refactor the `DataClasses.dbml`.